# How to stop a file poller and close the related application context?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am working on a project where I use a FilePoller that listens to a directory and calls a batch job on receiving any file. I invoke/start the process by just calling the Main class [from a scheduler and passing in argument like "startPoller"] and inside the main method, I just load the application context and things works like a charm.

Our Web Admin wants a way to kill/stop this FilePoller by invoking the same Main class again [with argument as "stopPoller"]. I tried using  but didn't work out as it has no way to identify/relate to the initially created application context.

Is there a way to stop the FilePoller and close the respective application context through external calls? I really need to stop and start the poller whenever I want. Am I missing something in my code?

Code to invoke/start the process:

```
    public class Main {
     public static void main (String args[]){
       if(args[0].equals("startPoller")) {
          ConfigurableApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                        "poller-context.xml");
          } 

      if(args[0].equals("stopPoller")){
               //I am stuck here...I can't get reference to the above created context/Job so as to stop/close them.

           /* This did not work out since its stopping the adapter on the            newly created context [ac] and not the one running already [context].

            ConfigurableApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "poller-context.xml");

            MessageChannel controlChannel = ac.getBean("inboundFileChannel", MessageChannel.class);


            Message<String> operation = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@filePoller.stop()").build();

            //controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@filePoller.shutdown()"));

            controlChannel.send(operation);

            ac.close();

            */

         }
          }

          }
```

Configuration XML:

```
             <int:channel id="inboundFileChannel" />
<int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller"
    channel="inboundFileChannel" directory="file:${pollFileInboundPath}"
    filename-pattern="*.*">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
    output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
    <bean
        class="com.my.batch.listener.FileMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="processFileBatchJob" />
        <property name="fileName" value="inputFile" />
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway
    request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel" reply-     channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />

<int:control-bus input-channel="inboundFileChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that because the second execution is a different JVM; you could use a `Socket` for the communication:

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: start/stop <port>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    if ("start".equals(args[0])) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("poller-context.xml");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("stopping...");
        context.close();
        System.out.println("...stopped");
    }
    else if ("stop".equals(args[0])) {
        Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", port);
        socket.close();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Usage: start/stop <port>");
        System.exit(3);
    }

}
```

In this case, simply opening a socket closes the context. You could make it more sophisticated by only binding to localhost (for security) and/or send some cryptic command over the socket to close the context.

You then run with, say

```
start 9999
```

and

```
stop 9999
```

You have to pick a port that's not currently in use on your server.